# Find three different number $m,n, k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m, n, k\geq 3$ such that $mnk=2(mn+nk+mk)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In my research, I need to solve the equation $mnk=2(mn+nk+mk)$ in natural number set, such that $n, m, k\in\mathbb{N}$ are different  number  and $n, m, k\geq 3$.

I know that $(n, m, k)\in\{ (3, 7, 42), (3, 8, 24), (3, 9, 18), (3, 10, 15), (4, 5, 20),(4, 6, 12)\}$, but it is not clear for me that how obtain them?

Please help me to know it.

Comment: So it is $\frac1m+\frac1n+\frac1k=\frac12$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, $\frac1m+\frac1n+\frac1k=\frac12$. Wlog, $m<n<k$.

We have:

- $m>2$ (if $m=1,2$, the left side is too large)
- $m<6$ (even $\frac16+\frac17+\frac18$ is too small)

#### $m=3$

Then $\frac1n+\frac1k=\frac16$. You can't let $n$ be too large or the left side is too small. Even $\frac1{12}+\frac1{13}$ is too small. So examine $n$ running from $7$ through $11$ and see if $k$ is an integer.

#### $m=4$

Then $\frac1n+\frac1k=\frac14$. You can't let $n$ be too large or the left side is too small. Even $\frac1{8}+\frac1{9}$ is too small. So examine $n$ running from $5$ through $7$ and see if $k$ is an integer.

#### $m=5$

Then $\frac1n+\frac1k=\frac3{10}$. You can't let $n$ be too large or the left side is too small. Even $\frac1{7}+\frac1{8}$ is too small. So examine $n=6$ and see if $k$ is an integer.

Comment: So that's how it's tackled. Nice. +1.